# React.createElement error with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router} from 'react-router'
 render((
  <Router>
  </Router>
 ), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Gives error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass 

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I am using Browserify with Babel6 - here's the babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "livereactload/babel-transform",
            "imports": ["react"]
          }]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And package.json deps:

```
"axios": "^0.8.1",
"babel-core": "^6.3.26",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0-beta1",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.3.13",
"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.3.13",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.3.13",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.3.13",
"babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
"babelify": "^7.2.0",
"browserify": "^12.0.1",
"livereactload": "^2.1.0",
"react": "^0.14.5",
"react-addons-linked-state-mixin": "^0.14.5",
"react-dom": "^0.14.3",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
"react-mixin": "^1.1.0",
"react-proxy": "^1.1.2",
"react-redux": "^4.0.6",
"react-router": "^1.0.3",
"react-simple-router": "^0.1.6",
"reactify": "^1.1.1",
"redux": "^3.0.5",
"redux-devtools": "^3.0.1",
"redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
"redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.1",
"redux-form": "^4.0.7",
"redux-simple-router": "^1.0.2",
```

Browserify config:

```
var props = {
entries: [script],
cache: {},
packageCache: {},
plugin: isProd ? [] : (watch ? [watchify, livereactload] : [livereactload]),
transform: [
  ['babelify', {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
    plugins: [
      ['react-transform', {
        'transforms': [{
          'transform': 'livereactload/babel-transform',
          'imports': ['react']
        }]
      }]

    ]
  }],
  [envify, {}]
],
extensions: ['.jsx', '.js'],
debug: !isProd,
fullPaths: !isProd // for watchify
}
```

Suggestion? I am finding lots of issues on GH with this but no clear solution.  This is taken right off the examples on React Router site so not sure why I cannot get it working. The only diff is they use webpack.

Comment: What version should I be using? This is 1.0.3 straight from npm today

Comment: As a note, if you have a `.babelrc` you probably don't need to replicate it inside the browserify config.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli ah yes - didnt even realize. I went through the webpack nightmare and gave up so this is my working but uncleaned config :)

Comment: I believe `<Router>` can't be empty.

Comment: @Louy I get the error even with content from the React Router as their examples - I removed everything to bare minimum for clarity.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli - the dual babel config was actually the issue! You can post that as an answer.

Comment: It was? Weird. You probably understand why better, so you post the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue was odd - thanks to comment I was able to resolve it. I have a `.babelrc` config as well as a `browserify` gulp job with its own babel config. For some reason having both created this issue. I deleted the one in gulp and now things work fine. Reason: I have zero idea.